# How do I identify in a string that a letter has a number beside?

Tags: c++, string, qt

I need to verify that a string line contains a specific word (M3), and this word contains a number in it. The problem is that the number is not always the same. Is there a way to verify a number in Qt C++?

I tried this, obviously not working:

```
if (line.contains("M"+"%i")) {
    qDebug() << "contains the word";
}
```

Comment: assuming the value of the number is in i, `"M" + QString::number(i)`

Comment: Your first step is to formally write down your requirements. As is, they are too vague and nebulous to be useful. For example, does the string "FOO BARM78 BAZ" contain your magic word, or not? Depending on how one would interpret the question, the answer could be either yes, or no. And without knowing what needs to be done, obviously it would not be possible to offer any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to search for certain patterns in a string. Since C++11 the C++ language contains a [regular expression library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) that can be used to work with regular expressions.

Simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string s;
  //Fill s with the text you want to check for the pattern here!
  // I'll use a fixed value here, but you'll need to change that.
  s = "bla M5 bla";
  //regular expression for "letter M followed by one digit"
  std::regex myRegex("M\\d");
  //std::regex_search checks whether there is a match between the
  // given sequence s and the regular expression. Returns true, if
  // there is a match. Returns false otherwise.
  if (std::regex_search(s, myRegex))
  {
    std::cout << "Text contains the search pattern.\n";
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "Text does not contain the search pattern.\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Of course, if your numbers can be more than one digit, you will have to adjust the regular expression accordingly.

Comment: THANKS! this helped me a lot, i actually used another class since im using QT, theres one called `QRegExp` that works just like `regex`